# Why is content of my file deleted when i try to read it? open function python

Tags: python, file

I made this code. I'm trying to give myself 2 options, 1 to login and 2 to register. When I register, everything works, it encrypts my text into sha256 and writes it into file, but when I try to "login", the open read function deletes content of file Login.txt, so the check fails.

```
import hashlib

#Creating file to save token into.
login_file = open("Login.txt", "w")

def register():
     print("Please insert your token:")
     reg_token = input()
     #Encrypting and writing token into file.
     login_file.write(hashlib.sha256(reg_token.encode()).hexdigest())
     login_file.close()
     print("Registration completed.")

def login():
    token_file = open("Login.txt", "r").read()
    print("Please login with your token:")
    log_token = input()
    #Calculating hash for input.
    hash = hashlib.sha256(log_token.encode()).hexdigest()
    #Comparing hashes.
    if hash == token_file:
        print("Success!")

    if hash != token_file:
        print("Login was unsuccessful.")

def prompt():
    print("For login type 1. For registration type 2.")
    prompt_input = input()
    if prompt_input == "1":
        login()
    if prompt_input == "2":
        register()

prompt()
```

Comment: You are opening the file in write mode *every* time, even when you only want to read from it. The first line should probably be inside the function `register`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line where you first open the file should be inside the `register()` function.
2. The second argument to [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) determines how the file is handled. `”w”` deletes the content first. `”a”` will allow you to append to the file.